# Rasplex HDMI Audio

Tags: audio, hdmi

I'm running the latest version of Rasplex on my Pi, connected to my TV by HDMI. The video playback is working fine. Unfortunately, I'm getting no audio at all, and all of my googling and fiddling with settings hasn't fixed this. I've also checked that the audio isn't being put out through the 3.5mm jack, and it isn't.

How can I fix this? Heck, how can I even debug it? I have ssh set up and ready to go if I need to fiddle with internal settings or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

Edit `/boot/config.txt`, make sure `hdmi_drive=2` is uncommented, save and reboot. More options can be found [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).